# Free or commercial SCP library needed for .Net project

Tags: .net, ssh, scp

I'm in the need for a SCP library (free or commercial) to be used in a .Net 3.5 project. I've already had a look at [SharpSSH](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) but it lacks the a couple of basic features (like enumerating all files in a remote directory). Do you know a good, solid and cheap library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need it to be SCP or SFTP? SCP is part of SSH1 protocol, which is considered to be insecure (due to certain design flaws). SFTP is part of SSH2, modern version of the protocol.

You can find the [comparison of different SFTP components for .NET here](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/sftpcompare.php).

Comment: Don't confuse SCP as program and SCP protocol. I was talking about the protocol.